# Customized popup for react leaflet library

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I was researching how I could open up a popup dialog on a marker to always be within the view dialog and not render outside the screen.  I came across https://github.com/erictheise/rrose and https://github.com/yafred/leaflet-responsive-popup.

Ended up going with responsive popup, and using https://medium.com/@nikjohn/creating-a-dynamic-jsx-marker-with-react-leaflet-f75fff2ddb9 to figure out how to generate jsx content within the popup.  However, I can't quite figure out how to bind this popup to the react-leaflet marker.

```
let customPopup = new L.ResponsivePopup().setContent(ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<div></div>));

<Marker position={position} icon={icon} key={`${headline.id}${key}`}>
          <Popup autoPan={false}> //Existing way, how to use the custom popup?
            <span>
              My Content Here
            </span>
          </Popup>
</Marker>
```

Any sort of guidance would be very helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem did you figure  out how to use responsive popup with react leaflet

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who sees this in future this is how I got this working:

```
import * as R from "leaflet-responsive-popup"

...

const markerRef = useRef()

useEffect(() => {
  const popupHtml = <PopupContent ... />
  const popupContent = new R.responsivePopup().setContent(renderToString(popupHtml))

  markerRef.current.bindPopup(popupContent)
}, [])

...

return <Marker ref={markerRef} ... />
```